# Flutter run waiting for connection from debug service on chrome

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use flutter on window 10, when i run flutter on console and perform flutter run -d chrome, the error is waiting for connection from debug service on chrome. The error from chrome page show "The connection cant be reach".

My flutter doctor show i didnt install Visual Studio, but i already used to the Visual Studio Code. Is it a must to install Visual Studio ?  Other than that, everything is passed.

I try to run the app on Visual Studio Code, the error is the same.  Even on edge, on web-server. The error is the same.

I try to add Dart Debug Extension on Chrome but cannot be enable. Can some help ?

My flutter run -d chrome --verbose show below :

```
[tag:C:\Users\Administrator\myflutter_app>flutter run -d chrome --verbose

[  +10 ms] <- compile org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart
[+19685 ms] Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome... (completed in 20.0s)
[   +2 ms] Synced 30.6MB.
[   +1 ms] <- accept
[        ] Caching compiled dill
[+2477 ms] [CHROME]:
[  +18 ms] [CHROME]: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57469/devtools/browser/51db6ac9-54b7-4fb7-bdb4-    25fb1707d9d6]
```

Comment: can you check your internet connection

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by performing the following actions

- Upgraded flutter to latest version
- Reinstall android studio
- run flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
- upgrade your chrome to latest

if you are using any extension in VS code to run flutter then there is also a possibility that the extension is not working properly try to change the version.

If it works give me a upvote,I'm new here.